# Firefox -- cannot remove cookies

Tags: macos, firefox

I've tried the suggestions from related questions but the problem persists. 
First noticed with `Firefox` version 20 - upgraded today to `Firefox` 21 - still cannot clear cookies.

Selecting gmail or stackoverflow the login and password are auto filled in the form - even after clearing all history, and then re-starting Firefox. Also after clearing all history, Firefox - Preferences - Privacy - Remove Individual Cookies - Clear all cookies, still gmail login and password are auto-filled.

OS is OS X 10.6.8 Mountain Lion.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Saved Passwords feature of firefox. To remove these goto Preferences - Security - Saved Passwords. Select Saved Passwords and remove individually or all.

[image: Security tab of Preferences]

Answer (score 2):

A few things could be causing this.

Check that there aren't any Firefox Extensions/Addons that save the information instead of Firefox, which could be causing a conflict.

Did you also clear your form history? [Control whether Firefox automatically fills in forms](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-firefox-automatically-fills-in-forms)

Firefox stores history and form history in a database called *places.sqlite*. If this is corrupted clearing any history data doesn't do anything. [Locked or damaged places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locked_or_damaged_places.sqlite)

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. It was saved passwords that was the issue. These are not removed when Clearing all history.